# Encrypt SQL Server traffic on a LAN

Tags: encryption, tls, certificates, sql-server

I have a .NET client application that runs on several machines on a local area network. All machines (including the server which is running MSSQL Server 2016) are running either Windows 7, 8 or 10. The server is also running the client software. How can I set it up so that the data traffic between all client machines and the server is encrypted in both directions?
The more I research this topic and that of digital certificates, the more confused I become.

- To achieve this, do I simply have to set "Force Encryption" to "Yes" in SQL Server?
- Do I need to install a certificate for this to work? If so, how do I get a suitable certificate?
- Can I simply generate a certificate myself. If so, how do I actually do that?